# Passing value from ionic to php curl

Tags: php, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, curl

I am trying to learn curl. I need to pass a variable from Ionic to PHP file.

Here is the code so far, I want to write the variable passed instead of hardcoded value `"Saurabh\"`

**Ionic / Angular .ts code**

```
  create_person_name(){
  console.log(this.val1);
  console.log('inside function');
  let empname= this.val1;
 //let msg = "Thank you for trusting KRANTI PRODUCTS. Your Complaint Number is: " + this.ticketnumber;
  let params = '&empname='+this.val1;
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  return this._http.post("https://example.com/" + "create-person-name.php", params, {headers: headers})
  .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
```

**PHP**

How do I mention `&empname` in place of `"Saurabh\"`?

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/persongroups/2/persons",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{  \r\n    \"name\" : \"Saurabh\",  \r\n    \"userData\" : \"TCO\" ,\r\n    \"recognitionModel\": \"recognition_02\"\r\n}",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the post fields like this...

```
"{  \r\n    \"name\" : \"{$_POST['empname']}\",  \r\n    \"userData\" : \"TCO\" ,\r\n    \"recognitionModel\": \"recognition_02\"\r\n}",
```

You could build this with and array and then json_encode it...

```
$fields = array(
    'name' => $_POST['empname'],
    'userData' => 'TCO',
    'recognitionModel' => 'recognition_02',
);
```

And then update the curl array with

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($fields)

Comment: this is some api, i just copied it and wanted to pass the name, i'll test it the way you guided and come back